# How can I track what package is used during WorkSpace Advanced Session using Cognos Audit DB

Tags: cognos, audit

I am attempting to count how many times a Workspace Advanced session is launched per package. Right now I am using the COGIPF_ACTION table to count instances of "/Configuration/User Interface Profiles/Report Studio Profiles/Professional" under the COGIPF_TARGET_PATH. This tells me when Report Studio or Workspace Advanced has been launched. How can I connect these rows to the specific package that was used for the RS or WSA launch?

Answer (score 1):

That kind of information is in `COGIPF_RUNREPORT`.  The package is in the `COGIPF_PACKAGE` column.  I'm pretty sure you can derive the tool used from the same table, although I don't know if you can tell Report Studio from Workspace Advanced.

Comment: I do not want to count every report run, only individual WSA sessions.

Comment: You should be able to join the 2 tables together using cogipf_sessionid.

Comment: That will not work because you can have multiple report runs / WSA launches under 1 session ID. You end up with ballooned counts.